# How is Cole not dead after he injects himself with his old DNA?

Tags: 12-monkeys-2015

In 12 Monkeys S01 E12 - Paradox, Cole injects himself with DNA from his younger self. The injection is accompanied with a massive explosion destroying everything around. Cole, (already weak at this point), manages to survive (being at the epicenter of the explosion). What enables him to survive this?

Comment: I'm a little confused. Are you saying he should have died in the explosion or because of the DNA injection?

Comment: I believe that TheChetan means that the DNA injection is the cause of the explosion. It is established in the series that when an object/person gets in contact with future/past self, it results in a paradox and an explosion. Check the first paragraph in [here](http://12-monkeys.wikia.com/wiki/Paradox_(event)), spoilers after 1st paragraph!

Comment: @Edlothiad He should have died from the explosion. They give some reason in the series to why the dna injection will work. But no mention of how he would survive the explosion.

Comment: When Cole used the watches to create a Paradox, at least one of them I remember being intact after the explosion. Maybe the source of the paradox is not affected. I don't know how far I got watching the show, but I could say there are so more paradox involving bones that seems to work the same way